# Significato di 'alla buona' in una pubblicità del 1932

Tags: word-usage, grammar

Sapreste chiarire cosa significhi e quale sia l'origine di 'alla buona' che vedete scritto in questa pubblicità del 1932?

Inoltre, è ancora in uso nella lingua contemporanea?

[image]

Comment: Le due indicazioni dell'anno sono curiose, perché non coincidono: sulla sinistra dice 1932, ma sulla destra è indicato l'anno XV dell'“era fascista”, cioè il 1937 (o, per la precisione, dal 28 ottobre 1936 al 27 ottobre del 1937).

Comment: @dag interessante questa considerazione.

Comment: @DaG, con la massima serietà, sai che ora che ci faccio caso mi rendo conto di non capire cosa significhi 'doppietta' in quel manifesto!? Hai un'idea?

Comment: Non sono un grande esperto di case di tolleranza, ma “doppietta” farebbe pensare a un doppio rapporto, anche se consumare il tutto in meno di mezz'ora pare improbabile. Qualcuno ha qualche idea?

Comment: This document can't be from 1932: the font of the bottom two lines of text is Arial, which was developed in 1982.

Comment: @jogloran You did an interesting observation.

Comment: @dag, hai letto il commento di jogloran . Pare ci sia un altra discordanza nel cartello (oltre quella che segnalasti tu). La questione inizia a diventare intrigante.

Answer (score 4):

La locuzione 'alla buona' è ancora vastamente utilizzata, soprattutto nel parlato, per indicare qualcosa di non particolarmente ricercato, informale: per citare [Wikipedia](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossario_delle_frasi_fatte#Alla_buona), è 'alla buona' qualcosa di fatto `senza particolare puntiglio o precisione`.

Per quanto concerne le sue origini, [Google Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=alla%20buona&year_start=1000&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calla%20buona%3B%2Cc0) suggerisce che questa locuzione non è stata utilizzata prima della seconda metà del '500 (ma questo non significa necessariamente che sia quello il periodo in cui compare come elemento a sè, in quanto può essere anche utilizzata accostata ad un nome femminile), ma non si trova nulla riguardo la sua etimologia: è possibile tuttavia supporre che l'uso di "buona" voglia essere una forma di apprezzamento per ciò che non è particolarmente ricercato ed è quindi "senza pretese" e che può a volte sembrare familiare e rassicurante.

Comment: Molti degli esempi di Google Books non sono della frase fatta che hai citato, ma del costrutto "alla buona" + nome femminile. Dunque, attenzione a come interpretare i risultati di Ngram viewer.

Comment: @Charo hai ragione, non ci avevo pensato: ho aggiornato la mia risposta